# How to format currency in fatfree framework

Tags: php, currency, fat-free-framework

I need to format currency in fatfree framework but i cannot understand how to avoid decimal

with

```
 {0 ,number, currency}
```

i receive (of course) € 11.000,00

but with

```
{0 ,number, currency,int}
```

I have EUR 11.000,00

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The `currency` filter doesn't allow to define the number of decimals.

You can however [create your own filter](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/preview#filter) to fit exactly your needs.

Here's an example:

```
$tpl=Template::instance();
// declare a new filter named 'price'
$tpl->filter('price',function($price,$decimals=0){
  return money_format('%.'.$decimals.'n',$price);
});
// test it:
echo $tpl->resolve('{{ 12 | price }}'); // € 12
echo $tpl->resolve('{{ 12.56 | price }}'); // € 13
echo $tpl->resolve('{{ 12.56, 2 | price }}'); // € 12,56
```